# UseDefaultcredentials is not working for Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: windows, powershell-4.0, invoke-restmethod

Getting unauthorized 401 error when I'm trying to invoke monster API using Invoke-RestMethod with property UseDefaultCredentials.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://monster.factset.com/loadbalancerapi/api/Node/viewAll' -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType 'application/json' -DisableKeepAlive
```

Same query successfully executing in another server with same configuration.

**I'm getting successful response by passing credential parameter.**

Do we need to enable any other feature to support UseDefaultCredentials (**Server: Windows Server 2012R2, Powershell version:4.0**)